# Connections between Fibonacci and natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

Here are some known facts about the Fibonacci numbers and then some questions regarding them .

> 1.Carmichael's theorem : For every $n>12$ $F_n$ has a prime divisor which doesn't divide any of the numbers $F_m$ with $m<n$ .

(I'd like to see a proof of this but maybe it's too hard )

This has a striking similarity with Zsigmondy's theorem and this similarity makes much more sense when we think about the well-known formula for $F_n$:
$$F_n=\frac{x^n-y^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$ (difference of powers like in Zsigmondy's but they're not integers )

> 2.The gcd property . It's well-known that :
>   $$(F_n,F_m)=F_{(n,m)}$$

Looking again at the representation of $F_n$ we make the connection with the following :

$$(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n)=a^{(n,m)}-b^{(n,m)}$$

As a corollary of this we can get : $$F_n \mid F_{kn}$$ which has the correspondent :

$$a^n-b^n \mid a^{kn}-b^{kn}$$

> 3.The fact that $$F_{p-\left( \frac{p}{5} \right )} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$ for $p$ a prime.

(I'd like to see a proof of this )

It seems like an equivalent to FLT in some way .Because of the difference of powers it seems connected with $a^{p-1}-b^{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

> 4.The Fibonacci binomial coefficients . The numbers :
>   $$\binom{m+n}{n}_F=\frac{F_{m+n} \cdot \ldots \cdot F_{m+1}}{F_{n} \cdot \ldots \cdot F_1}$$ are always integers.

(I'd like to see a proof of this also ).

This seems to be a $q$-analog of the binomial coefficients .

Now I have three main questions :

- What other such similarities exist between Fibonacci numbers and natural numbers?
- Why these things really happen ?? I'd accept any proofs (for 1 , 3 or 4 ) but I am especially searching for some reasons of why things work exactly this way .Maybe someone can show us the big picture of why this stuff really works (hope you get what I mean ) .
- What other sequences have such remarkable properties ? (ex what about Lucas's , Pell's or any other sequences ?)

I'd appreciate any answers to these questions .Thank you for all the help.

**EDIT**
Another nice fact about Fibonacci numbers is this :

> 5.The lifting lemma . If $a \mid F_n$ then $a^{k+1} \mid F_{na^k}$ for every $k$ .

(found here [An analogue of Hensel's lifting for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872955/an-analogue-of-hensels-lifting-for-fibonacci-numbers) )

This is clearly related with the LTE lemma :

$$v_p(a^{nk}-b^{nk})=v_p(a^k-b^k) +v_p(n)$$

I have also a new question .

- Is it true that $v_p(F_{nk})=v_p(F_{k})+v_p(n)$ with $p$ prime which divides $F_k$ (the above lifting theorem for Fibonacci numbers would be a corollary of this )?

Is this true? (I have some doubts ) .What do you think ?

Comment: In 5., what is $v_p$?  I had not seen Carmichael's theorem (1.) but I note that it provides yet another proof that there is no largest prime.

Comment: @user254665  $v_p(n)$ is the highest power of $p$ which divides $n$ (where $p$ is prime ) . For example : $v_2(100)=2$ , $v_5(100)=2$ and $v_7(7^{100})=100$ .