# Fibonacci number ending with given sequence of digits

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872071/fibonacci-number-that-ends-with-2014-zeros):

> For any given sequence of digits, does a Fibonacci number exist ending with such sequence?

If not, it would be nice to find the smallest counterexample. *(in other words, for example, showing that no Fibonacci number ends in, let's say, 12345)*

I tried several approaches (like in answers to the linked question), but none of them worked.

Comment: A strategy would be to consider the mapping of $\{F_n\}$ to the integers modulo $10^{d}$. Then the statement amounts to asking whether the mapping is surjective, since otherwise one can construct a counterexample.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872071/fibonacci-number-that-ends-with-2014-zeros.

Comment: For no particular reason, $F_{155} = 110560307156090817237632754212345$

Comment: Given the counterexamples below, maybe the question should be modified to asking how to characterize them. (For instance, should we expect to see counterexamples modulo 10000?)

Comment: It's certain that no number congruent to any of [4,6,10,12,14,18,20,22,26,28,30] mod 32 will occur in the Fibonacci series.  From my data it appears that all other residues of $10^n$ are present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No fibonacci number is congruent to 4 or 6 modulo 8.  They cycle [0,1,1,2,3,5,0,5,5,2,7,1]
.  So modulo 1000 there are numbers you can't reach.

More info:

$$\begin{align}
\text{modulus} && \text{Fibonacci period} && \text{# of missing residues} \\
2 && 3 && 0\\
2^2 && 6 && 0\\
2^3 && 12 && 2\\
2^5 && 48 && 11 = 2^5 \cdot \frac{11}{32}\\
2^8 && 3 \cdot 2^7 && 88 = 2^8 \cdot \frac{11}{32} \\
2^{15} && 3 \cdot 2^{14} && 5637 = 2^{15} \cdot \frac{11}{32} \\
2^{16} && 3 \cdot 2^{15} && 11264 = 2^{16}\cdot \frac{11}{32} \\
2^{20} && 3 \cdot 2^{19} && 360448 = 2^{20} \cdot \frac{11}{32} \\
5 && 20 && 0 \\
5^2 && 100 && 0 \\
5^3 && 500 && 0 \\
5^4 && 2500 && 0 \\
10 && 60 && 0 \\
10^2 && 300 && 0 \\
10^3 && 1500 && 250 \\
10^4 && 15000 && 3125 = 10^4 \cdot \frac{5}{16}\\
10^5 && 150000 && 34375 = 10^5 \cdot \frac{11}{32}\\
10^6 && 1500000 && 343750 = 10^6 \cdot \frac{11}{32}\\
\end{align}$$

Conjectures:

Modulo $2^n$, the period is $3 \cdot 2^{n-1}$.  For $n \ge 5$, exactly $\frac{11}{32}$ of the residues will not be present in the cycle.

Modulo $5^n$, the period is $4 \cdot 5^n$.  All residues are present.

Modulo $10^n$, for $n \ge 3$, the period is $15 \cdot 10^{n-1}$.  For $n \ge 5$, exactly $\frac{11}{32}$ of the residues will be missing.

Comment: Is there an analogous result for higher powers? I'd imagine so but an argument would be neat.

Comment: Obviously, if none are congruent to 4 or 6 modulo 8, then none are congruent to 4, 6, 12, or 14 modulo 16.  It turns out none are congruent to 10 either.

Comment: That recurring factor of 11/32 is bizarre to me. Any idea about the cause?

Answer (score 2):

A small brute-force search is enough to find several 3 digit sequences that are not ends of a fibonnaci number. Here are a few:
004, 006, 012, 014, 020, ...

All one and two digit possibilities appear.