# How to prove a claim about Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I have to prove that for any natural number $n$ there exists $i>0$ such that $n\mid F_i$, where $F_i$ is the $i$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: That follows from $F_0=0$ and the fact that the Fibonacci sequence $\pmod{n}$ is periodic.

Comment: Deeply related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872071/fibonacci-number-that-ends-with-2014-zeros/872077#872077

Comment: As to how to prove periodicity, consider that you can run the sequence 'backwards' - given $F_{i+1}$ and $F_{i+2}$ you can find $F_i$, so if you can show that the sequence $\{F_k\}$ repeats some of its values then it must repeat _all_ of its values.