# Show that exist $i>0$ such that the Fibonacci number $F_{i}$ is divisible by 2015

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

This is a problem that has haunted me for more than a month. Not all the time - but from time to time, and always on windy or rainy days, it suddenly reappears in my mind:

> Assume that the sequence $\{F_{n}\}$ of Fibonacci numbers is defined by the recurrence relation:
>
> $$F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} ,F_{1}=F_{2}=1.$$
>
> Prove that there exist $i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, such that $\dfrac{F_{i}}{2015}\in \mathbb{Z}$, and find the minimun of such $i$s.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872071/fibonacci-number-that-ends-with-2014-zeros/872077#872077

Comment: Oh,Nice ,you mean this? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PisanoPeriod.html,and use Chinese remainder theorem?But How to find minium of this $i$ also use Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have a complete solution. It is well-known (and easy to prove) that the Fibonacci sequence is periodic modulo any prime. To require $2015\mid F_n$ is the same as requiring
$$ 5\mid F_n\quad\wedge\quad 13\mid F_n\quad\wedge\quad 31\mid F_n. \tag{1}$$
Now, by direct inspection of the sequence modulo $5,13,31$, we have:
$$ 5\mid F_n \Longrightarrow 5\mid n, $$
$$ 13\mid F_n \Longrightarrow 7\mid n, $$
$$ 31\mid F_n \Longrightarrow 30\mid n,\tag{2} $$
hence the minimum positive $n$ such that $2015\mid F_n$ is $n=7\cdot 30 = \color{red}{210}.$
$$\begin{eqnarray*} F_{210}&=&34507973060837282187130139035400899082304280\\&=&2015\cdot 17125544943343564360858629794243622373352.\tag{3} \end{eqnarray*}$$