# Fun with fibonacci --find one divisible by 2014 and prove it

Tags: number-theory

Show that there exists a Fibonacci number that is divisible by 2014.i s this as simple as showing an nth F(n) is divisible by 2? A prime factor of 2014 . Some reason tonight my math faculties only at 40% :)

Comment: Related : (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266156)

Answer (score 4):

$F(0)=0$ is a multiple of $2014$.

---

Suppose we exclude $0$, it is still true. Lets take the first two values $n<m$ such that $F(n)\equiv F(m)\bmod 2014$  and $F(n+1)\equiv F(m+1)\bmod 2014$ (they must exist since there are only $2014^2$ options for $(F(n),F(n+1))\bmod 2014$ ).

We must have $n=0$, otherwise notice $F(n-1)\equiv F(n+1)-F(n)\equiv F(m+1)-F(m)\equiv F(m-1)$, contradicting the minimality of $n$.

Therefore $F(m)\equiv F(0)\equiv 0\bmod 2014$. We are done.

Comment: What about excluding 0?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss You may want to know that generally for any $n$, there is such a $m$ that $F_{m}$ is divisible by $n$. However, finding such a $m$ is not always easy.

Comment: @S.C.B., no, although if $n$ is squarefree we can do some magic with matrices.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling You mean we can't do it for all $n$? My book says that you can.

Comment: @S.C.B. I meant that if $n$ is square free we can find an explicit $k$ such that $n|F(k)$, using matrices.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling OK, thanks for clarifying your meaning.