# Proving that a Fibonacci number is divisible by integer a

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I am working on a review problem and can't figure out how to go about getting to an answer. We are told to let $F_n$ be the $nth$ Fibonacci number (defined as $F_1=F_2=1,F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$). Show that, for any positive integer a, there is some $N>0$ such that $F_N $is divisible by a. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Consider the Fibonacci numbers modulo $a$. At any point if you know _two_ successive numbers in the sequence you can work both forward and backward uniquely. And there are only $a^2$ possible such pairs, so sooner or later you will reach a pair that you have seen before. Because each pair has only one predecessor, this means that the initial pair $(1,1)$ is part of a _cycle_, and immediately before that comes the pair $(0,1)$, which corresponds to a number divisible by $a$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm What is the "initial pair" and why is it (1,1)?

Comment: @dalastboss: $(F_1,F_2)\equiv(1,1)\pmod a$.

Comment: Oh okay, gotcha, thanks

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel (cycle) - [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34795/242) and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/744335/242) for hints.