# can $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$ generate prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of integers given by the rule $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1$, Does there exists a value for $a_0$ for which the sequence consists entirely of prime numbers.

Comment: If $a_0=p$ is an odd prime, then $a_{p-1}$ is divisible by $p$ by FLT. Remaining case $a_0=2$ is simple.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66258/242) for a *proof* of a more general result (replace $10x+1$ by $2x+1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Mod any odd prime $p$, the sequence is periodic with period at most $p-1$.  If $p$ is a prime divisor of $a_1$, $a_n$ will again be divisible by $p$ (and thus not prime) for some $n$ with $2 \le n \le p$.